# Laravel create PDF syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I open in Laravel link to create a *PDF* I got this error:

> **syntax error**, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Here is a snippet of the **code** that laravel highlight:

```
$customer_data = kunden::find($id);
 ->where('id', '=', $id)
 ->first();
```

I changed to:
    $customer_data = kunden::find($id);

Bot now i got this error:

> Class 'MVS\Http\Controllers\Kunden' not found

I have a Controller in Http/Controllers with the name **KundenController**

The content from that controller is the following code:

```
<?php

namespace MVS\Http\Controllers;

use MVS\Kunden;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class KundenController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function index()
{
    $kunden = Kunden::all();

return view('admin.kunden.index', compact('kunden'));
}


/*

Funktion das nur eingeloggte Benutzer Kunden anlegen können

*/



public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}


/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function create()
{
    return view('admin.kunden.create');    }

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request,
    [
        'vorname' => 'required',
        'nachname' => 'required',
        'strasse' => 'required',
        'plz' => 'required',
        'wohnort' => 'required',
        'mail' => 'required',
        'telefon' => 'required',
        'geburtsdatum' => 'required'

    ]
);

$kunden = new kunden();
$kunden->user_id = auth()->id();
$kunden->vorname = request('vorname');
$kunden->nachname = request('nachname');
$kunden->strasse = request('strasse');
$kunden->plz = request('plz');
$kunden->wohnort = request('wohnort');
$kunden->mail = request('mail');
$kunden->telefon = request('telefon');
$kunden->geburtsdatum = request('geburtsdatum');
$kunden->kaufpreis = request('kaufpreis');
$kunden->kostenumbau = request('kostenumbau');
$kunden->kostennotar = request('kostennotar');
$kunden->grunderwerbssteuer = request('grunderwerbssteuer');
$kunden->maklerkosten = request('maklerkosten');
$kunden->gesamtkosten = request('gesamtkosten');
$kunden->eigenkapital = request('eigenkapital');
$kunden->finanzierungsbedarf = request('finanzierungsbedarf');
$kunden->save();
 return redirect('/admin/kunden');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \MVS\Kunden  $kunden
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Kunden $kunden)
{
     return view('admin.kunden.show', compact('kunden'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \MVS\Kunden  $kunden
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Kunden $kunden)
{
    return view('admin.kunden.edit', compact('kunden'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \MVS\Kunden  $kunden
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, Kunden $kunden)
{
    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'vorname' => 'required',
        'nachname' => 'required',
        'strasse' => 'required',
        'plz' => 'required',
        'wohnort' => 'required',
        'mail' => 'required',
        'telefon' => 'required',
        'geburtsdatum' => 'required'

    ]
);


$kunden->vorname = request('vorname');
$kunden->nachname = request('nachname');
$kunden->strasse = request('strasse');
$kunden->plz = request('plz');
$kunden->wohnort = request('wohnort');
$kunden->mail = request('mail');
$kunden->telefon = request('telefon');
$kunden->geburtsdatum = request('geburtsdatum');
$kunden->kaufpreis = request('kaufpreis');
$kunden->kostenumbau = request('kostenumbau');
$kunden->kostennotar = request('kostennotar');
$kunden->grunderwerbssteuer = request('grunderwerbssteuer');
$kunden->maklerkosten = request('maklerkosten');
$kunden->gesamtkosten = request('gesamtkosten');
$kunden->eigenkapital = request('eigenkapital');
$kunden->finanzierungsbedarf = request('finanzierungsbedarf');

$kunden->save();
 return redirect('/admin/kunden');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \MVS\Kunden  $kunden
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Kunden $kunden)
{
     $kunden->delete();

return back();    }


}
```

The Route for that app is:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 'DynamicPDFController@get_customer_data');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('admin/kunden', 'KundenController');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/dynamic_pdf', 'DynamicPDFController@index');

Route::get('/dynamic_pdf/pdf', 'DynamicPDFController@pdf');
```

The Path to the Model is app/Kunden.php

the content is:

```
<?php

namespace MVS;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kunden extends Model
{
//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
$customer_data = kunden::find($id);
```

Comment: correct - i got a new Error :S
Class 'MVS\Http\Controllers\Kunden' not found

Comment: You will need to `use App\Kunden` in your class or create the `Kunden` model.

Comment: I created a model called "Kunden". I update my post for the code :)

Comment: Where is your `Kunden` file found? Can you add to your question?

Comment: Its updated :) i hope it helpd. When not say what you need- Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
use App\Kunden; //kunden is your model
```

do this

```
$customerData = Kunden::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
```

or

```
$customerData = kunden::find($id);
```

Comment: When searching for `id`, you can use the `find()` eloquent method instead of `where()`

Comment: I added but get another failure:

Class 'MVS\Http\Controllers\kunden' not found

Comment: your model name ? and path of maodel @DierigPatrick

Comment: @KuldeepMishra updated

Comment: the Path is app/Kunden.php and model name is Kunden

Comment: @DierigPatrick i have updated the code please check

Comment: @KuldeepMishra i trief it before you wrote it - it doesnt work :( i cry >.<